# Is there any way to suggest a file name with a data URI?

Tags: javascript, html, data-uri

I am using data attribute to simulate a file download from client-side JavaScript. Here's my source code :

```
var data = "data:application/text,anything is here";
window.location.href = data;
```

This works perfectly and simulates a file download. Is there any way I can specify the file name as well, as a part of the data URI or by using some other facility available from the browser?

I am aware of the `download` attribute of `<a>` tags, but I was wondering if there are any options other than the default which is to use the value of `data` itself as the suggested file name.

Comment: So where the data comes from?

Comment: I'm generating the data from a client side JavaScript Application, it's a JSON manifest generator, everything is happening client side.

Comment: You can simulate this dynamically by adding `<a` with attributes `href` and `download` and trigger the click at the end remove the element

Comment: I was thinking about the same solution. but i was wondering if there are any better ones.

Comment: didn't find any solution, did it by simulating a click on an A element. can you post the comment as an answer, so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way of doing it when you are redirecting the browser like that.

If you were instead provide the download via link you could use the [`download` attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) to suggest a filename. Not all browsers [support the `download` attribute`](http://caniuse.com/#search=download) at this time.